# Changing class of 1 trigger when triggering the other. (1 action with 2 triggers)

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I want to achieve is to toggle the color class of the TRIGGER1 when I trigger the the number 2 (the input).
To see my problem, click first TRIGGER1 and then TRIGGER2. The box gets closed but the first trigger's class doesn't change

HTML

```
<button id="trigger1" class="color-front" >TRIGGER1</button>
<input id="trigger2" type="text" placeholder="TRIGGER2">
<div id="boxToOpenOnTrigger" class="color-back elem-hide"></div>
```

CSS

```
.elem-hide{ display: none; }
.color-back{ background-color: #3d3d2d; }
.color-front{ background-color: white; }
#boxToOpenOnTrigger{ width: 300px; height: 300px; }
```

jQuery

```
$('#trigger1').on('click', function(){
    $( this ).removeClass('color-front');
    $( this ).toggleClass('color-back');
    $( "#boxToOpenOnTrigger" ).toggleClass('elem-hide');
});

$('#trigger2').on('click', function(){
    if ( $("#trigger1").hasClass( "color-back" ) ) {
        $( this ).removeClass( "color-back" );
        $( this ).addClass( "color-front" );
    } 
    $( "#boxToOpenOnTrigger" ).addClass('elem-hide');
});
```

I hope you understand me, my english is not very good yet :/

https://jsfiddle.net/gtagc01g/

Answer (score 3):

JS

```
   $('#trigger1').on('click', function(){
        $( this ).removeClass('color-front');
        $( this ).toggleClass('color-back');
        $( "#boxToOpenOnTrigger" ).toggleClass('elem-hide');
    });

    $('#trigger2').on('click', function(){

        var trigger1=$("#trigger1");
        if (trigger1.hasClass( "color-back" ) ) {
            trigger1.removeClass( "color-back" );
            trigger1.addClass( "color-front" );
        } 
        $( "#boxToOpenOnTrigger" ).addClass('elem-hide');
    });
```

> Note you were using `this` inside a onclick event `trigger2` which refers to `trigger2`

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gtagc01g/3/)

Comment: Ohh I thought I was referring to the IF's id!!

Comment: Sidenote: I would recommend to cache `$('#trigger1')` inside a variable as it's used several times. Also you can chain the class-functions. This would tidy up the code a bit.

Comment: @empiric Done as u said :)

Comment: @KawineshSK I will use it just in this action. Would you recomend me to make a variable in this case?

Comment: @EderIraizoz it purely your wish no harm done in both the ways just while in using varibale we are tiding the code and make it more easy for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understood your question well, but i will try to answer.

When you click on trigger2, you want to add the class "color-font" to trigger 1 ?

If it's the case, do it like this :

```
 $('#trigger2').on('click', function(){
    if ( $("#trigger1").hasClass( "color-back" ) ) {
        $( this ).removeClass( "color-back" );
        $("#trigger1").addClass( "color-front" );
    } 
    $( "#boxToOpenOnTrigger" ).addClass('elem-hide');
});
```